# Jenkins throws "Client does not have permissions to send as this sender"

Tags: email, jenkins, smtp

There is lots of posts with users having same error, but none of them works for me...

I am trying to send email reports in `Hudson/Jenkins`...

Our mail server uses SSL/TLS, I configured Jenkins for TLS, then I am getting this error:

```
Client does not have permissions to send as this sender
```

When I try `javamail` using code, it sends the email properly. Also, Thunderbird works fine.

Any ideas? Do I need to contact mail server administrators?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Finally got it, thanks to [Friso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693526/how-can-i-set-the-senders-address-in-jenkins)

Had to set my email address in `System Admin e-mail address` under `Jenkins Location`.

Comment: This work to me, so mail server will not recognize as spam anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The email should be changed in three places as below as per version 2.19.4:

Extended E-mail Notification - If using SMTP plugin

Email Notification - SMTP Authentication

Jenkins location - System Admin e-mail address

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I discovered that credentials were no more valid, so I asked to the IT department who told me that credentials were no more need on LAN.

Now it works!