# Client does not have permissions to send as this sender in Jenkins

Tags: email, jenkins, outlook, smtp

I installed Jenkins (Jenkins ver. 2.46.2) and i have configured SMTP Server in `Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Email Notification`.
Test mail is works fine. But in Job email notification not working.

```
Error message as : Error sending to the following VALID addresses
```

I checked the Jenkins log file.

```
550 5.7.60 SMTP; Client does not have permissions to send as this sender [KL1PR03MB1749.apcprd03.prod.outlook.com]
DEBUG SMTP: got response code 550, with response: 550 5.7.60 SMTP; Client does not have permissions to send as this sender [KL1PR03MB1749.apcprd03.prod.outlook.com]

RSET
250 2.0.0 Resetting
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 550 5.7.60 SMTP; Client does not have permissions to send as this sender [KL1PR03MB1749.apcprd03.prod.outlook.com]

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2057)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.finishData(SMTPTransport.java:1862)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1100)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:195)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher.sendMail(ExtendedEmailPublisher.java:357)
    at hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher._perform(ExtendedEmailPublisher.java:322)
    at hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher.perform(ExtendedEmailPublisher.java:230)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:720)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.cleanUp(Build.java:196)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1775)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)
QUIT
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set "System Admin email address" under Manage Jenkins -> Configure System. This is under the Jenkins Location header on that page!

Have a look at below thread.
[How can I set the Sender's address in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693526/how-can-i-set-the-senders-address-in-jenkins)

Comment: I already set that in System Admin Email Address. Then only test mail will get success